# Not able to generate all the Kaprekar Number in a range

Tags: java, algorithm

Though the problem seemed simple, here it is :-

A Kaprekar number is a positive whole number n with d digits, such that when we split its square into two pieces - a right hand piece r with d digits and a left hand piece l that contains the remaining d or d−1 digits, the sum of the pieces is equal to the original number (i.e. l + r = n).
The Task 
You are given the two positive integers p and q, where p is lower than q. Write a program to determine how many Kaprekar numbers are there in the range between p and q (both inclusive) and display them all.

Input Format

There will be two lines of input: p, lowest value q, highest value

Constraints:

```
0<p<q<100000
```

Output Format

Output each Kaprekar number in the given range, space-separated on a single line. If no Kaprekar numbers exist in the given range, print INVALID RANGE.

I could not clear the test cases in the range

```
22223
99999
```

In the above range the follwoing numbers should have been generated :-

```
77778 82656 95121 99999
```

Here is my code :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int p = scan.nextInt();
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        boolean exist = false;
        if(q <= p){
            System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
        }
        int m = 0,n = 0;
        long sqr = 0;
        String numb = "";
        String[] digits = new String[2];
        for(int i = p; i <= q; i++){
            if(i == 1)System.out.print(1 + " ");
            else{
            sqr = i*i;
            numb = String.valueOf(sqr);// Changing it into a string.
            if(numb.length() % 2 == 0){
                digits[0] = numb.substring(0, numb.length()/2);//Splitting it into two parts
                digits[1] = numb.substring(numb.length()/2);
            }else{
                digits[0] = numb.substring(0, (numb.length() - 1)/2);
                digits[1] = numb.substring((numb.length() -1)/2);
            }
              if(digits[0] == "" )
                  m = 0;
              if(digits[1] == "")
                  n = 0;
              if(!digits[1].equals("") && !digits[0].equals("")){
              m = Integer.parseInt(digits[0]);
              n = Integer.parseInt(digits[1]);
              }  
            if(i == (m + n) ){ //Testing for equality
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                exist = true;
            }
        }
      }
        if(exist == false){// If exist is never modified print Invalid Range.
            System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making `i` long, or casting the `i` as you square it so that the `i*i` is definitely performed as long. Also IIRC Kaprekar numbers aren't necessarily split in the middle - I think you're missing one in that range. (And there are better ways of splitting a number into digits than to-string, substring, parse.)

Comment: Yes you fixed it in one shot. But the max value of Long as they say is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. So I ruled that out as a possible source of error. Correct me, I guess my understanding is wrong.

Comment: OK, but `long sqr = i*i;` will be carried out as multiply-ints then promote the answer to long, not promote-to-long then multiply, so you're hitting the int limit which is lower.

Comment: Also you suggested that I should not be resorting to string for splitting a number into digits. Please kindly elaborate more on that. Please write that suggestion in the answer I will accept that.

Comment: I'm not sure how much help to give you since this reads like an assignment, but you can do it using standard integer operations. That said it won't make much difference over small number ranges like the one you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type of Loop index i from int to long fixed the problem.

The square computation of i*i was overflowing the upper limit of int so by changing it to long we were able to get the required computation done.

Thanks to Rup for pointing this out.

The code which cleared all the test cases is here :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int p = scan.nextInt();
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        boolean exist = false;
        if(q <= p){
            System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
            return;
        }
        int m = 0,n = 0;
        long sqr = 0;
        String numb = "";
        String[] digits = new String[2];
        for(long i = p; i <= q; i++){
            if(i == 1)System.out.print(1 + " ");
            else{
            sqr = i*i;
            numb = String.valueOf(sqr);
            if(numb.length() % 2 == 0){
                digits[0] = numb.substring(0, numb.length()/2);
                digits[1] = numb.substring(numb.length()/2);
            }else{
                digits[0] = numb.substring(0, (numb.length() - 1)/2);
                digits[1] = numb.substring((numb.length() -1)/2);
            }
              if(digits[0] == "" )
                  m = 0;
              if(digits[1] == "")
                  n = 0;
              if(!digits[1].equals("") && !digits[0].equals("")){
              m = Integer.parseInt(digits[0]);
              n = Integer.parseInt(digits[1]);
              }  
            if(i == (m + n) ){ 
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                exist = true;
            }
        }
      }
        if(exist == false){
            System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kaprekar
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int num=sc.nextInt(); 
int sq=num*num; String sq1=Integer.toString(sq);
int mid=(Integer.toString(sq).length())/2;
int rem=sq%((int)Math.pow(10,sq1.length()-mid));
int quo=sq/((int)Math.pow(10,sq1.length()-mid));
int sum=rem+quo;
if(sum==num)
{System.out.println("Kaprekar");}else{System.out.println("Not Kaprecar");}
```

}
   }

Comment: Thus is most simple way to do it

Comment: If you mean dividing by powers of 10 then yes I agree, although for this particular question you've made the same mistake as the OP by using int not long and so 99999*99999 will overflow. (Note also that these aren't real Kaprekar numbers, since in the normal definition there's no requirement that the split is in the middle as we've got in the HackerRank definition.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class Kaprekar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int p = scanner.nextInt();
        int q = scanner.nextInt();
        long i,n,s,a,c,k,d,e=0;

        for(i=p;i<=q;i++)
        { 
            k=i;d=0;
            while(k!=0)
            { 
                d++;
                k=k/10;
             }
            c=0;s=0;n=i*i;
            while(n!=0)
            {
                a=n%10;
                n=n/10;
                s=s+ (int)Math.pow(10,c)*a;
                c++;
                if(n+s==i&&(c==d||c==d-1)&&s!=0)
                { 
                    System.out.print(i+" ");
                    e++; break;
                }
              }
             }
        if(e==0)
        {
         System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
         }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```